# How do we get props or states in navigationOptions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm getting errors on calling props or states on navigationOptions. How do we get props or states in navigationOptions?

Here is PostDetailScreen which render user's name and user's id.

```
class PostDetail extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    header: (
        <View>
            <Text>{this.state.username} {this.props.user.id}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
});
```

Comment: @WayneC Is this very difficult question? I can't even find this on Google.

Comment: Look through https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1639 and https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting here as I don't have access to comment option.
Where have you defined the state.username, also make sure if you've passed the user.id as props from the parent container from where class PostDetail has been called.
Please post the error and question in more detail.

Comment: Um I solved this problem already. I just decided not to use navigationOptions.

Comment: Thanks for asking though! Thanks!